How to use alt-else-end together with manual activation in PlantUml
Here below is a sequence diagram that describes how a user signs in to an application:
@startuml
autonumber
actor Individual as individual <<registered>>
boundary "Sign In Page" as signInPage <<ui>>
control "Auth Service" as auth
entity User as user
database Repository as repo

individual -> signInPage ++ : enter username or email
individual -> signInPage : enter password
individual -> signInPage : sign in
signInPage -> auth ++ : auth user
auth -> repo ++ : get user by username or email
return user
auth -> auth ++-- : granted = user exists and credentials are correct
return granted
alt granted is true
autonumber stop
autonumber 9 1
signInPage -> signInPage ++-- : redirect to home page
signInPage --> individual : home page
else granted is false
autonumber stop
autonumber 9 1
signInPage -> signInPage ++-- : redirect to error page
return error page
end
@enduml

The diagram above gets rendered correctly...

but the alt implementation is ugly at least. If access is granted, the Sign In Page shall redirect to the home page; otherwise, if access is denied, the Sign In Page shall redirect to an error page. As you can see, to deal with manual activation, in the alt part I have to send back a message to Individual, whereas in the else part I have to use a return statement. Is there any better way to represent this?

I've added the diagram, and I'm trying to understand your question about manual activation. It seems to me that steps 7 and 9 are not necessarily messages, which would invoke new stack space (method calls). They're rather operations that happen. Could you not use notes, e.g., note over auth: granted = user exists and credentials are correct instead of the message? As for 9, I don't think you need that step at all. Just return the page. You could get rid of the alt and just use note over signInPage: page = granted ? home page : error page

Here's an answer based on my comments on the question above.
@startuml
'round the notes to look like activity boxes
skinparam roundcorner 10
autonumber
actor Individual as individual <<registered>>
boundary "Sign In Page" as signInPage <<ui>>
control "Auth Service" as auth
entity User as user
database Repository as repo

individual -> signInPage ++ : enter username or email
individual -> signInPage : enter password
individual -> signInPage : sign in
signInPage -> auth ++ : auth user
auth -> repo ++ : get user by username or email
return user
rnote over auth: granted = user exists\nand credentials\nare correct
return granted
rnote over signInPage: page = granted ?\nlogin page :\nerror page
return page
@enduml


